# Dynamically get List ID from List Name

Tags: list, visual-web-part

In my Visual webpart I need to, based on the name of a list get the ID of the list, dynamically. I'm using C#.

How can this be done?

Comment: Can you please add some details on what you are tring to do? Alos you have tagged the question with SPServices, and C#. Those are very different frameworks.

Comment: i have List name in that that list name i want to getting That List ID

Comment: please help this post

Comment: Client object model or server object model?

Answer (score 4):

You should always select your list based on the URL, as the Title is more likely to change. And don't do SPWeb.Lists as this will enumerate all lists on the web site. Use this similar snippet instead:

```
public Guid? GetListId(string siteUrl, string listUrl)
{
    using (var currentSite = new SPSite(siteUrl))
    {
        using (var currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
        {
            try
            {
                var spList = currentWeb.GetList(SPUtility.ConcatUrls(currentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, listUrl));
                return spList.ID;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //List was not found.
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you returning the `GUID`? Your function seems to have a return type of GUID, but there is no return statement.

Comment: In a magical way :) Updated the answer.

Comment: This will not compile, you are not returning anything in case of an exception ;)

Comment: The example was to provide an understanding of the concept. OP will change the snippet most probably. Updated anyway :)

Comment: I know I know, just wanted to be a little bit of a pain in the ass ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try following method if you are using Server Object Model. I did not test my code. Written from top of head. test and let me know

```
public Guid? GetListId(string siteUrl, string listName)
        {
            using (var currentSite = new SPSite(siteUrl))
            {
                using (var currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    var spList = currentWeb.TryGetList(listName);
                    if (spList != null)
                    {
                        return spList.ID;
                    }else{
                      return null;
                     }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Update based on comment

```
var listIdAsString = GetListId("siteUrl", "list") == null ? "" : GetListId("siteUrl", "list").ToString();
```

Comment: i used your code but Error in Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection" GetByTitle()" Error Like does not contain definition   for "GetByTitle"

Comment: my answer is update. use TryGetList instead of GetByTitle. Thanks @Robert

Comment: Ya i use your updated code but Error "GetListId(string siteUrl, string listName)" Error msg: not all code paths return value

Comment: All paths have return value. Though add else with if. See my update

Comment: ya i use your code but How to get the return value or how to store the return value into String ?

Comment: var listIdAsString = GetListId("siteUrl", "list") == null ? "" : GetListId("siteUrl", "list").ToString(); and see update

Comment: i Try to call the function like : "var result = GetListId(spWebUrl,listname);" but Error : only assignment increment,Call,decrements....

Comment: Same Issue, Error : only assignment increment,Call,decrements...